# Does $c(f) = \gcd(\{ f(n) | n \in \mathbb{Z} \})$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Consider $\sum_{i = 0}^n a_i x^i \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Recall that the content of a polynomial is the gcd of its coefficients. I'm wondering whether the content is equal to $\gcd ( \{ \sum_{i = 0}^n a_i k^i | k \in \mathbb{Z}  \} )$.

Context: I thought of the question when trying to think of a proof of Gauss's lemma, in which it is shown that c(fg) = c(f)c(g) for any two polynomials f and g. Of course the question above is true for degree 1 polynomials and constant polynomials, and so it seemed natural that it would hold for all degrees (and so I never thought to look for counterexamples in higher degrees as described below).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that's the reason for the down vote.

Comment: Consider the polynomial $x+x^2$,  values always divisible by $2$  Or $x^3-x$, values always divisible by $6$. Or many others.

Comment: Thanks. So it's much simpler than I thought then.

Comment: You are welcome. In each of the examples, the content is $1$ but the gcd of the values is greater than $1$. If you look at the plynomial $(x+1)(x+2)\cdot (x+n)$ the content is $1$ but the gcd of the values is $n!$.

Comment: "much simpler" ? not sure. @AndréNicolas : in general, how would you compute his $c(P)$ (or $C(P,n) = gcd(P(n),P(n+1),P(n+3),\ldots)$) just by looking at the polynomial $P$ ? and if you obtain $n!$ you are considering $gcd(P(x)) \ \mid \ x \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @user1952009: The question asked whether the gcd of the values is equal to the content. Examples show the answer is not necessarily. For a **general** polynomial, finding the gcd of the values is feasible, but not particularly simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(X)\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ be *integer-valued* (i.e., $f(k)\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$).  If $f(X)$ is of degree $n$, then $f(X)=\sum_{i=0}^n\,A_i\,\binom{X}{i}$ for some $A_0,A_1,\ldots,A_n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  If the *modified content* $\tilde{C}(f)$ of $f$ is defined to be the gcd of all the $A_i$'s, then $\tilde{C}(f)$ is precisely the gcd of all $f(k)$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

In Andre Nicolas's first example, $X^2+X=0\binom{X}{0}+2\binom{X}{1}+2\binom{X}{2}$ so that $\gcd(0,2,2)=2$ is the gcd of all $k^2+k$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  For the second one, $X^3-X=0\binom{X}{0}+0\binom{X}{1}+6\binom{x}{2}+6\binom{X}{3}$ so that $\gcd(0,0,6,6)=6$ is the gcd of all $k^3-k$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I believe that this is also true.  Let $S$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ such that, for every prime $p\in\mathbb{N}$, integer $r>0$, and $j\in\left\{0,1,2,\ldots,p^r-1\right\}$, there exists $s\in S$ such that $s\equiv j\pmod{p^r}$.  Then, $\tilde{C}(f)$ is also the gcd of all $f(k)$ for $k\in S$.

> Why do I need the ridiculous requirement on $S$?  First, it is clear that $S$ should be infinite for the gcd to be established for every integer-valued polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.  Then, it follows that, for any $j\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\gcd(S-j)=1$, otherwise $f(X)=X-j$ is a counterexample.  This implies that $\gcd(S-S)=1$.  However, this is still not enough (originally, I thought $\gcd(S-S)=1$ would be sufficient as mentioned in some of the comments below).  If there exist a prime $p\in\mathbb{N}$, an integer $r>0$, and $j\in\left\{0,1,2,\ldots,p^r-1\right\}$ such that $s\not\equiv j\pmod{p^r}$ for all $s\in S$, then we may assume that $j=p^r-1$ and consider $f(X)=\binom{X}{p^r-1}$.  In this case, $\tilde{C}(f)=1$ but it is easily seen by [Lucas's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) that $p$ divides $f(k)$ for all $k\in S$.  Hence, $s\equiv j\pmod{p^r}$ must have a solution $s\in S$ in order to satisfy the condition that $\tilde{C}(f)$ is the gcd of $f(k)$ for $k\in S$.

Comment: great ! and by induction it is easy showing that every polynomial of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ can be decomposed in this form. the algorithm : find $A_n$ first, substract the polynomial $A_n {X \choose n}$, then find $A_{n-1}$, etc.

Comment: (and I don't see why you start with $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ and not $\mathbb{Z}[X]$)

Comment: I am allowing polynomials, for example, of the form $f(X)=\frac{X^p-X}{p}$, where $p\in\mathbb{N}$ is prime, which takes integer values for $X\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: right, I didn't notice those kind of weird polynomials

Comment: and why do you consider the set of differences $a-b $ ? what is the prototypal example of such a set ?

Comment: Yes, the set of prime numbers works, or the set of Fibonacci numbers, or just the set of natural numbers.  I have to require that the gcd of $S-S$ must be $1$, and not just that the gcd of $S$ is $1$, otherwise $f(X)=X-1$ for $S$ consisting of all odd numbers would be a counterexample.

Comment: I did not find anything similar to your trick for computing $gcd(f(1),f(2), \ldots)$, after having searched "[rising factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)"+polynomials+gcd things like that

Comment: Are you asking for a proof?  If so, a hint is to show that $\gcd\big(f(0),f(1),\ldots,f(n)\big)=\tilde{C}(f)$ for integer-valued polynomial $f(X)\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ of degree $n$.  If you are asking for a reference, I have no idea.  I just pulled it out of my head when I replied 30 minutes or so ago.

Comment: Nah, I'm sure it is known by some number theorists.  The only thing I invented is probably my conjecture with a set $S$.