# GCD of $n^a\,\prod\limits_{i=1}^k\,\left(n^{b_i}-n\right)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $a$ be a nonnegative integer.  For a given positive integer $k$, let $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k$ be odd integers greater than $1$.  Using this [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849603/the-greatest-common-divisor-of-all-numbers-of-the-form-na-nb?noredirect=1&lq=1), it can be shown that, for each integer $n$, $$f_{a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k}(n):=n^a\,\prod_{i=1}^k\,\left(n^{b_i}-n\right)$$
is divisible by
$$\Gamma\left(a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k\right):=2^{\min\left\{k+a\,,\,2k+\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\,v_2\left(b_i-1\right)\right\}}\,\prod_{\substack{{p\in\mathbb{Z}_{>2}}\\p\text{ prime}}}\,p^{t_p}\,,$$
where
$$t_p:={\min\left\{k+a\,,\,\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1|b_i-1}}}\,\big(1+v_p\left(b_i-1\right)\big)\right\}}
$$
for each prime $p>2$.  Here, $v_q(m)$ denotes the largest exponent $\nu\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ such that the $\nu$-th power of the given prime $q$ divides the integer $m$.

> **Question.** Fix $a$ and $\left(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k\right)$.  What is the greatest common divisor $G\left(a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k\right)$ of all integers of the form $f_{a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k}(n)$ (i.e., $n$ runs over all the integers)?  Is it equal to $\Gamma\left(a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k\right)$?  If not, what is a counterexample?

At least, we know that $G\left(a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k\right)=\Gamma\left(a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k\right)$ in the following examples.

1. Case $k=1$: See this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849603/the-greatest-common-divisor-of-all-numbers-of-the-form-na-nb?noredirect=1&lq=1).
2. Case $a=0$, $k=2$, and $\left(b_1,b_2\right)=\left(13,17\right)$:  See this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384312/prove-that-n30-n14-n18n2-is-divisible-by-46410?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Here is another [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784489/the-gcd-of-a-univariate-integer-valued-polynomial-over-a-set?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that$$G\left(a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k\right)=\Gamma\left(a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k\right)$$

*Proof* :

We can write
$$f_{a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k}(n)=n^{k+a}\prod_{i=1}^{k}\bigg(n^{b_i-1}-1\bigg)$$

Firstly, let us prove that
$$v_2\bigg(G\left(a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k\right)\bigg)=\min\left\{k+a\,,\,2k+\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\,v_2\left(b_i-1\right)\right\}\tag1$$

- If $n$ is even, then $v_2(f_{a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k}(n))=v_2(n^{k+a})\ge k+a$ where the equality is attained when $n=2$.
- If $n$ is odd, then using the following lemma ([Lifting The Exponent](http://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvYy82LzdjNTI1OGIyMmNjYmZkZGY4MDhhY2ViZTc3MGE1NDRmMzFhMTEzLnBkZg==&rn=TGlmdGluZyBUaGUgRXhwb25lbnQgTGVtbWEgLSBBbWlyIEhvc3NlaW4gUGFydmFyZGkgLSBWZXJzaW9uIDMucGRm) for $p=2$) :
  $$v_2(n^{b_i-1}-1)=\begin{cases}v_2(n - 1) + v_2(b_i-1)&\text{if $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$}
  \\\\v_2(n + 1) + v_2(b_i-1)&\text{if $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$}\end{cases}$$
  we get $$\small v_2(f_{a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k}(n))=v_2\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{k}\bigg(n^{b_i-1}-1\bigg)\bigg)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}v_2\bigg(n^{b_i-1}-1\bigg)\ge \sum_{i=1}^{k}\bigg(2 + v_2(b_i-1)\bigg)$$ where the equality is attained when $n=5$.

Therefore, $(1)$ follows.

---

Secondly, let us prove that $$v_p\bigg(G\left(a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k\right)\bigg)={\min\left\{k+a\,,\,\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1|b_i-1}}}\,\big(1+v_p\left(b_i-1\right)\big)\right\}}\tag2$$
where $p$ is an odd prime.

- For $n$ such that $n\equiv 0\pmod p$, $v_p(f_{a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k}(n))=v_p(n^{k+a})\ge k+a$ where the equality is attained when $n=p$.
- For $n$ such that $n\not\equiv 0\pmod p$, using the followig lemma (Lifting The Exponent) : 
  If $p\mid x-1$, then $v_p(x^{m} - 1) = v_p(x- 1) + v_p(m)$
  and letting $b_i-1=(p-1)p^{m_i}u_i$ where $m_i,u_i$ are non-negative integers with $\gcd(p,u_i)=1$, we have$$v_p(n^{b_i-1}-1)=v_p((n^{p-1})^{p^{m_i}u_i}-1)=v_p(n^{p-1}-1)+v_p(p^{m_i}u_i)\ge 1+v_p(b_i-1)$$So, it follows that$$\begin{align}v_p(f_{a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k}(n))&=\underbrace{\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1\ \not\mid\ b_i-1}}}\,v_p(n^{b_i-1}-1)}_{\ge 0}+\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1|b_i-1}}}\,v_p(n^{b_i-1}-1)
  \\\\&\ge\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1|b_i-1}}}\,\big(1+v_p\left(b_i-1\right)\big)\end{align}$$In the following, let us prove that the equality of this inequality is attained either when $n=g$ or when $n=(1+p)g$ where $g$ is a primitive root of $p$. (I learned this idea from [Chris Wuthrich](https://mathoverflow.net/users/5015/chris-wuthrich).)
  If $v_p(g^1-1)=v_p(g^2-1)=\cdots=v_p(g^{p-2}-1)=0$ and $v_p(g^{p-1}-1)\color{red}{=1}$, then$$\begin{align}v_p(f_{a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k}(g))&=\underbrace{\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1\ \not\mid\ b_i-1}}}v_p\left(g^{b_i-1}-1\right)}_{=0}+\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1|b_i-1}}}v_p\left(g^{b_i-1}-1\right)
  \\\\&=\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1|b_i-1}}}\bigg(v_p(g^{p-1}-1)+v_p(b_i-1)\bigg)
  \\\\&=\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1|b_i-1}}}\bigg(1+v_p(b_i-1)\bigg)\end{align}$$
  If $v_p(g^1-1)=v_p(g^2-1)=\cdots=v_p(g^{p-2}-1)=0$ and $v_p(g^{p-1}-1)\color{red}{\ge 2}$, then there are integers $m_1,m_2$ such that$$\begin{align}&v_p(f_{a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k}((1+p)g))
  \\\\&=\underbrace{\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1\ \not\mid\ b_i-1}}}v_p\left(((1+p)g)^{b_i-1}-1\right)}_{=0}+\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1|b_i-1}}}v_p\left(((1+p)g)^{b_i-1}-1\right)
  \\\\&=\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1|b_i-1}}}\bigg(v_p((g+pg)^{p-1}-1)+v_p(b_i-1)\bigg)
  \\\\&=\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1|b_i-1}}}\bigg(v_p\bigg(g^{p-1}+(p-1)g^{p-2}pg+p^2m_1-1\bigg)+v_p(b_i-1)\bigg)
  \\\\&=\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1|b_i-1}}}\bigg(v_p(-p+p^2m_2)+v_p(b_i-1)\bigg)
  \\\\&=\sum\limits_{\substack{{1\leq i\leq k}\\{p-1|b_i-1}}}\bigg(1+v_p(b_i-1)\bigg)\end{align}$$

Therefore, $(2)$ follows.

---

It follows from $(1)(2)$ that$$G\left(a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k\right)=\Gamma\left(a;b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k\right)$$

Comment: Well done!  I checked, and everything worked out marvelously.  Thanks, man!

Comment: If you want to work on my other problems, I will award bounties to them to, even after you have answered them.

Comment: @Batominovski : You checked my answer so quickly! :)  I'll see your problems when I have time.

Comment: My problem was finding examples where the equality is attained.  So, I understood your proofs of the inequalities quite quickly.  You filled in the gap with the equality cases.